# Piranha CMS Manager Area

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

I am trying to create some custom forms in the manage area and have hit some speed bumps.

1.When I add another item to the new menu group it does not appear. I have 2 items in the group, the group shows in NAV but it only links to the first item. I am not sure how it is supposed to behave.

2.Also when I create additional custom views in the manager area MVC creates the shared folder and _layout view. Things dont work right then. the layout view has footers and other defined regions. Does not appear to be manager area related. I delete the shared view and it is fine.

3.Since it does not appear to have a _layoutview that is reachable in the manager area how can I add custom CSS and Javascript bundles.  i can get them to work with hard coding the path.

Thanks for your time!!! –

Comment: Hi H,  If I override the manager area with my own views its sounds that I would have to drop in my own layout, Css and scripts for the manager area.  As it sounds like there is no way to carry over the default style and menus for the Manager area.  Is this correct.  Thanks for you  help

Answer (score 1):

In the future, try using the piranhacms tag here at SO, this way the people interested will get email notifications!

Here's some answers in case you didn't get it working :)

**1**) If you've followed the guide on the homepage you might have added the following property to your menu item.

```
Permission = "ADMIN_PRODUCT"
```

This is just an example that you can set custom permissions for your views in the manager. Make sure you don't add a permissions that **doesn't exists** or your used doesn't have. In that case the menu item won't show up.

**2**) If you add Layout-views in the manager area these will be used instead of the ones embedded in the Piranha dll. This is actually a feature so you can override all of the default views. Unfortunately this doesn't always play well with the rather **STUPID** scaffolding in Visual Studio.

**3**) If you add the file:

```
~/Areas/Manager/Content/Css/Style.css
```

It will be used in the manager. Custom javascript you have to include from your custom views as there's no support for adding scripts into the manager layout. This is mainly to avoid possible conflicts between the scripts used by the manager and those you might include.

Best regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks for the response. Timing was good as I am jumping back into this project.   I did realize there was another tag for Piranha. My biggest issue with the manager area is that I cant get the Menus to work correctly.  I can't get items to drop down.